# How to on one page sequence decide begining of a new node to insert different header

Tags: xslt, xpath, xsl-fo

EDIT AFTER GETTING CORRECT RESULT:

Ok, I managed to do that. Basically when I understand what really @Kevin wants me to do, I created empty marker on the begining of topic (with keep-with-next), and after title of topic is created I changed it to normal header. Now everything is ok.

EDIT:

I tried @Kevin-Brown suggestion, but probably I did something wrong. I will show minimal version, to give an general image of that what happened.

I got:

```
flow
    block with normal header marker
    block with keep-with-next always, and empty marker which actually doesnt matter in my case
    block with content
```

and header looks like:

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:retrieve-marker retrieve-class-name="body-header-marker" retrieve-position="first-including-carryover" retrieve-boundary="page"/>
</fo:block>
```

Problem is that header is no really carryover. Because right now, even if I remove empty marker, I will have header on the page with the topic, and I won't have anything on next pages of topic. Then again I will have one again on the begining of the topic. What I did wrong?

OLD QUESTION:

I am working with Formatting Objects, and I have some problems with finding good (actually any) solution in same cases. Is there any way to check if currently processing node actually taking 2 pages?

Maybe if I try to define the problem, you can suggest some better solution. I have multiple topics in xml, and during processing of topic, I adding header and footer to every page. I want to change it, to not add header, on page where title of new topic is located (topic starts from new page). So maybe there is better way to do what I want, than checking pages. Because I think that because of different approach to "variables" in functional programming, I might be not able use page as I wanted.

Comment: If you have to change the header depending on some content of the page, you should use the [`<fo:marker>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_marker) and [`<fo:retrieve-marker>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_retrieve-marker) elements.

Comment: Sounds good. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general principle you want in pseudo markup is this:

```
block-container for topic
   throw marker containing the header for the topic
   ... content of topic ...
end block-container for topic

block-container with empty marker keep-with-next as "always"
   throw marker with nothing in it (basically clear the marker)
end block-container with empty marker 

block-container for topic
   throw marker containing the header for the topic
   ... content of topic ...
end block-container for topic

... and so on ...
```

So you pull the marker **first-including-carryover** into your header. This means the first marker whose parent container starts at the top or carry's over from the last page.

If your page starts perfectly with the start of a topic, the first marker on the page will be the empty one. This is because you are gluing the empty marker block-container to the start of every topic. There is no content in this structure, it will not corrupt your output. I did not show above putting the empty marker container above the first topic, but do that also if you want.

If your page breaks inside a topic, then the "carryover" marker would be pulled which would have the header of the topic from the previous page pulled. Normally this marker would include something like "- Continued" at the end.

Comment: Thank you. I will check ot next I will have time for it (which is probably Wednesday).

Comment: Nevermind, I edited answer again ;) Thank you for good solution

Answer (score 2):

You could put every topic in a separate `fo:page-sequence` and use an `fo:page-sequence-master` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence-master) to select a different `fo:simple-page-master` just for the first page.  You could make it so that page-master has a different header.

See, e.g., 'Switching the layout in facing pages automatically (page-sequence-master)' in http://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/comprehensive-xsl-fo-tutorials-and-samples-collection/, although you would probably want to select on `page-position="first"` rather than `odd-or-even`.

Comment: This sounds really good, but the problem is that I working with plugin, that is already big. And the thing is that I have page-master on body. And body have every chapter. So I think (but I am absolutely not sure, because I am new at it) that in that case first page will be always only first page of first chapter. And changing something that big might be problematic.

Comment: What plugin is that?  If you can't change the page-master selection, are you able to use `fo:marker` and `fo:retrieve-marker` as @potame suggested?

Comment: **com.docdept.pdf**. I tried, but I am having hard times with that. Because I was able to set up marker, but I was creating marker  in page-sequence (to be more accurate in fo:flow), so I think it will be always the same for one chapter, isn't it? At least it was in my example.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know anything about **com.docdept.pdf**.  If you can use `fo:retrieve-marker` with `retrieve-position="first-starting-within-page"`, then the marker should be retrieved only on the first page of the topic.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the request where the OP wants every topic in their own page sequence -- meaning that every topic starts a new page. That is what this solution does.

Comment: OP said "topic starts from new page".  From comment, markers were unfamiliar, so generating static content with each page sequence might have saved having to mess with markers, but we now know that's not an option given the framework being used.